# Javascript - Sorting array with objects based on objects value

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

So I am trying to sort my array with objects based on an objects value..

```
var mostCheapHistory [ { lowestTitle: title goes here, lowestPrice: 100 }, another obj, another, another } ]
```

And I want to sort them based on their price, so I came up with this:

```
var historyObj = mostCheapHistory[0];

for(var y in mostCheapHistory){
    nextObj = mostCheapHistory[y];

    console.log('Is '+ historyObj.lowestPrice + ' more as ' + nextObj.lowestPrice + ' ?');
    console.log(historyObj.lowestPrice > nextObj.lowestPrice);
    console.log('-----')
}
```

And this is the output...

```
Is 124.98 more as 124.98 ?
false
-----
Is 124.98 more as 18.59 ?
false
-----
Is 124.98 more as 25.9 ?
false
-----
Is 124.98 more as 26.99 ?
false
-----
Is 124.98 more as 34.76 ?
false
-----
```

What the hell is going on? It's obvious that 124.98 is more as 34.76 and yet it gives false?

The array is made using this code:

```
for(var x=0; x < items.length; x++){
            var title = items[x].title[0];
            var price = items[x].sellingStatus[0].currentPrice[0].__value__;

            var item = 
                { 
                    lowestPrice : price,
                    lowestTitle : title
                }

            if(x === 0){
                mostCheapHistory.push(item);                
            }
            else{
                for(var y=0; y < mostCheapHistory.length; y++){
                    if(mostCheapHistory[y].lowestPrice > price ){
                        if(mostCheapHistory.length < 5){
                            mostCheapHistory.push(item);
                            break;
                        }
                        else{
                            mostCheapHistory[y] = item;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: please add the sort part.

Comment: It's not sorting anything yet, because I can't really test if one value is bigger as another as you can see

Comment: please add the real data of the array.

Comment: the real data is retrieved from an outside API, but it's filled with objects 100% same to the first object

Comment: I added out how the array is generated

Comment: make sure the type of lowestPrice is string or float

Comment: My guess is that the numbers are actually strings `'124.98' > '34.76' => 
false`, try parsing the number (e.g. `parseFloat(historyObj.lowestPrice)` and comparing those

Comment: I think the comparison is being done on string type, that's why you are getting that result.

Comment: why don't you tell us how did  you resolve this bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the predefined sort function :

```
mostCheapHistory.sort(function(a,b){
    return a.lowestPrice - b.lowestPrice;
}
```

+ Your code might be pushing strings rather than numbers, which explains why `124.98 > 34.76 => true` but `'124.98' > '34.76' => false`, since the string '34.76' is greater than '124.98' in string comparison.
Use parseFloat() for the prices then check again.

Comment: This says nothing about why the code in the question produces the output that it does which is what was actually asked.

Comment: Indeed, this fixed the problem, thanks anyway :) But still wondering why Im getting that output

Comment: perhaps the you are appending strings rather than numbers, therefore `124.98 > 34.76 => true` but `'124.98' > '34.76' => false`

Answer (score 2):

It looks like, you are comparing strings instead of numerical values. If you say (in comments), that the sorting function

```
array.sort((a, b) =>  a.lowestPrice - b.lowestPrice);
```

solves your problem, then while this sort callback uses an implicit casting to number with the minus `-` operator.

The result is a sorted array with values as string.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort these based on price using Array.prototype.sort() ([See MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort))

e.g.

```
var data = [
{
  title: "title1",
  value: 123
},
{
  title: "title2",
  value: 324
},
{
  title: "title3",
  value: 142
}];

var sorted = data.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.value > b.value;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the type of lowestPrice is string not float, use parseFloat(historyObj.lowestPrice) to compare the two values